# How can I draw a graph using c?

Tags: c, windows, graph

I wrote a process explorer using C with GUI interface. I want to add a graph to show the CPU status. Which library or functions can help me to do that?

Comment: @EitanT: windows as I tagged.

Comment: sdl, windows gdi/gdi+, directx, gdk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/), it's a simple 2D graphics library written in C.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `curses` windows impelementation which called [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/) for High Performance Graphics